# Optimize a MySQL request that take long time to load with an ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm facing an issue of performance with a MySQL query, even with indexing the column needed, etc... It take more than 5 seconds to load the 10 firsts results and it's due to the `ORDER BY`, when I remove it, it take only few milliseconds to load!

Here is the SQL query:

```sql
select
    *
from
    `feedbacks` f
inner join carriers c on c.id = f.carrier_id 
where
    c.id in (25619, 25620, 25621, 25637, 25758, 25759, 25760, 25761, 25762, 25763, 25976, 25983, 26459, 26460, 27003, 27006, 27052, 27295, 27325, 27387, 27532, 27533, 27534, 27535, 27536, 27537, 27538, 27541, 27542, 27543)
    and f.`deleted_at` is null
order by
    f.`created_at` desc
limit 10 offset 0
```

There is some index on the `feedbacks` table:

```
feedbacks_status_id_foreign BTREE   FALSE   status_id
feedbacks_push_id_foreign   BTREE   FALSE   push_id
feedbacks_created_at_index  BTREE   FALSE   created_at
feedbacks_carrier_id_created_at_token_index BTREE   FALSE   carrier_id,created_at,token
feedback_test_index BTREE   FALSE   created_at,carrier_id
PRIMARY BTREE   TRUE    id
```

And inside the `carriers` table:

```
idx_creator_id  BTREE   FALSE   creator_id
carriers_team_id_foreign    BTREE   FALSE   team_id
carriers_slug_unique    BTREE   TRUE    slug
carriers_slug_organization_id_created_at_index  BTREE   FALSE   slug,created_at
PRIMARY BTREE   TRUE    id
```

But even with all of these indexes, it take a long time!

More help are welcome for this issue :D

Comment: please add an explain extended for the query and a show warnings output after run.

Comment: best way to show indexes is the output of `show create table yourtablename`; that's much more useful.  also add output of `explain extended select ...rest of your query`

Comment: MySQL can often use indexes either for selecting and joining data or for ordering, but not both. If it's using the index for selecting, it has to collect all the results before ordering, so it can't start returning data quickly.

Comment: @Barmar there is a feedback_test_index index that looks ideal here (unless the selected carriers are only a very small percentage of feedback rows), maybe the `c.id in` instead of `f.carrier_id in` is confusing it.  the explain will tell us a lot

Comment: You have NO index for table carrier.id to match to your f table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to find ids of the rows in questions, *then* fetch the extra columns.  This avoids hauling around lots of junk, through sorts, etc, and may allow for using "covering" indexes:

```
select  f2.*, c.*
    FROM  (
        SELECT  f.id
            FROM  `feedbacks` f
            WHERE  f.carrier_id in (25619, 25620, 25621, 25637, 25758,
                        25759, 25760, 25761, 25762, 25763, 25976, 25983, 26459,
                        26460, 27003, 27006, 27052, 27295, 27325, 27387, 27532,
                        27533, 27534, 27535, 27536, 27537, 27538, 27541, 27542,
                        27543 
                          )
              and  f.`deleted_at` is null
            order by  f.`created_at` desc
            limit  10 offset 0 
          ) AS f1
    JOIN  carriers AS c  ON c.id = f1.carrier_id
    JOIN  feedbacks AS f2  ON f2.id = f1.id
    ORDER BY  f2.`created_at` desc  -- yes, repeated
    ;
```

with:

```
feedbacks:  INDEX(deleted_at, carrier_id, created_at,  id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, we now take 300ms to load the data instead of 42seconds previously :) :)